# how to draw underground layer in harp.gl and set camera to it

Tags: harp.gl

How can we draw underground feature like pipeline and subway? I would like to have them appear to be underground and not merely on road level. Can we also set the map view port to underground level? in documentation, camera pitch angle can only be set 0 to 90 degree

Comment: It might help to include a [demonstration](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you're trying to do and where you're getting stuck.

Comment: i contacted the application engineer instead and seems like it is not a supported feature